# Multi Line Bulk Entries

Tags: php

Code : 
I have 3 multiline textbox, each of its contain some data, which will be used further to generate INSERT QUERY, DB contains 3 columns.

So these will be used for bulk entries

```
<form method="post">    
<textarea name="code" id="code" rows="20" cols="20" placeholder="code"></textarea>
<textarea name="name" id="name" rows="20" cols="20" placeholder="name"></textarea>
<textarea name="pack" id="pack" rows="20" cols="20" placeholder="package"></textarea><Br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $code = explode("\n", $_REQUEST['code']);
    $name = explode("\n", $_REQUEST['name']);
    $pack = explode("\n", $_REQUEST['pack']);
    /*foreach (array_combine($code, $name) as $mid => $mid1){
        echo "<br>";
        echo $mid;
        echo $mid1;
    }*/

    foreach ($code as $mid){
        foreach ($name as $mid1){
            foreach ($pack as $mid2){
            echo "INSERT INTO medi_medicines (`cc1`,`nn1`,`pp1`) VALUES('".$mid."','".$mid1."','".$mid2."')";
            echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Input ::

[Input image, here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIcfF.png)

Output ::

```
INSERT INTO medi_medicines (`cc1`,`nn1`,`pp1`) VALUES('demo ','1 ','a ')
INSERT INTO medi_medicines (`cc1`,`nn1`,`pp1`) VALUES('demo ','1 ','b')
INSERT INTO medi_medicines (`cc1`,`nn1`,`pp1`) VALUES('demo ','2','a ')
INSERT INTO medi_medicines (`cc1`,`nn1`,`pp1`) VALUES('demo ','2','b')
INSERT INTO medi_medicines (`cc1`,`nn1`,`pp1`) VALUES('demo1','1 ','a ')
INSERT INTO medi_medicines (`cc1`,`nn1`,`pp1`) VALUES('demo1','1 ','b')
INSERT INTO medi_medicines (`cc1`,`nn1`,`pp1`) VALUES('demo1','2','a ')
INSERT INTO medi_medicines (`cc1`,`nn1`,`pp1`) VALUES('demo1','2','b')
```

Expecting :

```
    INSERT INTO medi_medicines (`cc1`,`nn1`,`pp1`) VALUES('demo ','1 ','a ')
    INSERT INTO medi_medicines (`cc1`,`nn1`,`pp1`) VALUES('demo1 ','2 ','b ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because you nested loop 3 times. That's like 2x2x2.

You should do something like:

```
$queries = count($code); //This should be = 2
for($i=0;$i<$queries;$i++) {
    echo "...VALUES('".$code[$i]."','".$name[$i]."','".$pack[$i]."')";
}
```

//i have not tested this code
//sorry bad english